# Plotly: How to filter a pandas dataframe across multiple columns using a dropdown menu?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataset along the lines of:

| coin | date | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bitcoin | 2018-01-01 | 325 | 444 |
| bitcoin | 2018-01-02 | 425 | 444 |
| etherium | 2018-01-04 | 525 | 444 |
| bitcoin | 2018-01-06 | 325 | 444 |
| etherium | 2018-01-06 | 725 | 444 |

It has ten currencies and data for the entire year.

I am trying to compare the “Open” and “Close” values for all the currencies, by month, for the year. The scale of data for each currency is quite different so showing them all on the same chart doesnt work. I would like to have two dropdowns, one for month and one for currency. At the moment the code I'm using is:

```
q2df = df.loc[(df['Currency'] == "bitcoin") & (df['Date'] >= "2018-01-01") & (df['Date'] <= "2018-01-31")]

fig = px.line(q2df, x='Date', y=['Open', 'Close'])

fig.show()
```

What I want is to move the filtering from the data frame creation to two Plotly dropdown boxes. But I cant find anything on how to pass something like (df['Currency'] == "bitcoin") to plotly as an axis argument.

Comment: Have you looked at [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/)?  You can create drop-downs with a callback function to filter a dataframe prior to passing to plotly function.  This is a good example, though with a slider: [Figure and Slider](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks#dash-app-layout-with-figure-and-slider)